# Android Loader: Cannot load data to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, loader

The problem is that, I don't get any error, except that the data doesn't get loaded in the textViews of the customized ListView, all I get is a blank output. I didn't have problems before I started using Loaders.

**MSKFragment.java** (The Fragment class)

```
public class MSKFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
private ServiceAdapter mServiceAdapter;

public static final int SERVICE_LOADER = 0;

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle args)
{
    Uri serviceUri = ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.buildServiceUri(i);
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), serviceUri, null, null, null, null); 
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
{
    mServiceAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
{
    mServiceAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

public MSKFragment()
{

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_msk, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_refresh)
    {
        //Moving functions to a helper class, so that when Activity starts the data can be displayed
        updateServices();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mServiceAdapter = new ServiceAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_msk, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewMainService);

    listView.setAdapter(mServiceAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    //Refresh called and service updated when activity starts
    updateServices();
}

private void updateServices()
{
    FetchServicesTask serviceTask = new FetchServicesTask(getActivity());
    serviceTask.execute();
}

}
```

**ServiceAdapter.java** (Custom Adapter class)

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
public ServiceAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags)
{
    super(context, c, flags);
}

private String convertCursorRowToUXFormat(Cursor cursor) {
    // get row indices for our cursor
    int idx_name = cursor.getColumnIndex(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
    int idx_organizationName = cursor.getColumnIndex(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_NAME);
    int idx_price = cursor.getColumnIndex(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.COLUMN_PRICE);

    return cursor.getString(idx_name) + "-" + cursor.getString(idx_organizationName) +
            " - " + cursor.getString(idx_price);
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, parent, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView)view;
    tv.setText(convertCursorRowToUXFormat(cursor));
}
}
```

**FetchServicesTask.java**  (Performing the Async Task)

```
public class FetchServicesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>

{

private final String LOG_TAG = FetchServicesTask.class.getSimpleName();

private final Context mContext;

private boolean DEBUG = true;

public FetchServicesTask(Context context )
{
    mContext = context;
}

private String[] getServicesDatafromJson(String serviceJsonStr) throws JSONException
{
    final String MSK_NAME = "name";
    final String MSK_PRICE = "price";
    final String MSK_ORG_NAME = "organizationName";
    final String MSK_POSTED_USER = "postedUser";
    final String MSK_PROFILE = "profile";

    int totalResults = 25;
    String resultStrs[] = new String[totalResults];

    try
    {
        JSONArray serviceArray = new JSONArray(serviceJsonStr);

        Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<ContentValues>(serviceArray.length());

        for(int i=0;i<serviceArray.length();i++)
        {
            String name, organizationName, price;

            JSONObject serviceObject = serviceArray.getJSONObject(i);

            name =  serviceObject.getString(MSK_NAME);
            price = serviceObject.getString(MSK_PRICE);

            JSONObject postedUserObject = serviceObject.getJSONObject(MSK_POSTED_USER);
            JSONObject profileObject = postedUserObject.getJSONObject(MSK_PROFILE);

            organizationName = profileObject.getString(MSK_ORG_NAME);

            ContentValues serviceValues = new ContentValues();

            serviceValues.put(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            serviceValues.put(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_NAME, organizationName);
            serviceValues.put(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.COLUMN_PRICE, price);

            cVVector.add(serviceValues);
        }

        int inserted = 0;

        if(cVVector.size()>0)
        {
            ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[cVVector.size()];
            cVVector.toArray(cvArray);

            inserted = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(ServiceContract.ServiceEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FetchServicesTask Complete. " + inserted + " Inserted");
    }

    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/////////////////////////////// NETWORKING BOILER PLATE ///////////////////////////
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
{
    if (params.length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; //Streaming data using HTTP
    String serviceJsonStr = null; //raw JSON response
    BufferedReader reader = null; //read text from character i/p stream

    int pageNo = 1;
    int numResults = 5;

    try
    {
        //-------------------------CONNECTION--------------------//

        final String SERVICE_BASE_URL = "http://myservicekart.com/public/";
        final String SEARCH_BASE_URL = "http://myservicekart.com/public/search?";
        final String SEARCH_PARAM = "search";
        final String PAGE_PARAM = "pageno";


            /*Using a helper class UriBuilder for building and manipulating URI references*/

        Uri builtServiceUri = Uri.parse(SERVICE_BASE_URL);
        Uri builtSearchUri = Uri.parse(SEARCH_BASE_URL).buildUpon().
                appendQueryParameter(SEARCH_PARAM, "").
                appendQueryParameter(PAGE_PARAM, Integer.toString(pageNo)).
                build();

        URL searchUrl = new URL(builtSearchUri.toString());

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built SearchUri" +builtSearchUri.toString());

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) searchUrl.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.connect();

        //------------------------BUFFERING---------------------//

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        if(inputStream==null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if(buffer.length()==0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        serviceJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        getServicesDatafromJson(serviceJsonStr);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Services JSON String: " +serviceJsonStr);
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error cannot connect to URL", e);
        return null;
    }

    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        if(urlConnection!=null)
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        if(reader!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();
            }
            catch (final IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error closing stream",e);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: How about debugging it first yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In onCreate, you need to init your loader:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(SERVICE_LOADER , null, this);

// Or if you are using the support library, use this:
// getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(SERVICE_LOADER , null, this);
```

Comment: I guess this solution might help. But when adding this code in the Fragment actiivty, I get an error in the Main Activity, while adding the fragment. [Error:(54, 21) error: no suitable method found for add(int,MSKFragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MSKFragment cannot be converted to Fragment)]

Comment: That is a different problem, you are probably trying to use both the support Fragment and the normal Fragment in your code. Check that all code you are using is running on one or the other. If you use support fragments for example, make sure that you are also using getSupportFragmentManager(). Infact, it might be that you need to use getSupportLoadManager() instead, in the snippet I have posted in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, I've got it all working now